# ember data isLoad on collections

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use emberjs-data

```
allProcessPointsAreLoaded:(->
@get("reportDefinition.virtualColumns").everyProperty("processPoint.isLoaded", true)
).property("reportDefinition.virtualColumns.@each.processPoint.isLoaded")
```

my property is not updated when processPoint.isLoaded changed to true. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest ember-data has an isLoaded property on the whole content collection, instead of just each field. In my view I monitor the path 'controller.content.isLoaded' to determine when all the content is there.

Comment: I'm using `App.TablesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  test: function() {
    console.log(this.get("content").get("length"))
  }.observes("content.isLoaded")
});` to get the number of records in the ArrayController but it always logs 0. Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to get the correct count by using `.find({})` instead of `find()` see: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @each can only currently support one nested property `"reportDefinition.virtualColumns.@each.processPoint"` but not `"reportDefinition.virtualColumns.@each.processPoint.isLoaded"`. Here's the [github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541) that I found.

I've worked around it by adding a property to proxy to isLoaded. So you would have something like:

```
processPointLoaded: function() {return this.get('processPoint.isLoaded')}.property('processPoint.isLoaded')
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Question was about nested property in the @each, not only checking if collection is loaded.